# How to prevent dynamic import to duplicate a bundle?

Tags: webpack, react-redux, babeljs, code-splitting

I am creating a React/Redux App compiled with Babel and bundled by Webpack. I want to implement a plugin feature. So I use Code Splitting with Dynamic import() to divide the main bundle for each plugin. However, if I need the same plugin in many place, Webpack will bundle a bundle for any import() used and iterate it (0.bundle.js, 1.bundle.js, ...). I try to use webpackChunkName: "MyPlugin" in comment in import() thinking that if I import a bunble with the same chunk name, it will replace the other one while bundling, but since I use babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack, webpackChunkName don't seem to work anymore. Due to project privacy, I can't provide any testable demo. Any idea?

```
import( /* webpackChunkName: "MyPlugin" */ `./plugins/MyPlugin.jsx` );
```

.babelrc

```
{  
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env", 
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
        "dynamic-import-webpack",
        ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "ant"]
    ],
    "env": {
        "node": {
            "plugins": [
                ["babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore",
                {"extensions": [".less", ".scss", ".png", ".jpg"]}
            ]
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "presets": [["env", {"modules": "commonjs"}]]}
    },
    "comments": true
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
[...]
module.exports = {
    entry: entry,

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: "/",
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                            "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
                            "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
                            "dynamic-import-webpack",
                            ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "ant"]
                        ],
                        presets: [
                            "@babel/preset-env",
                            "@babel/preset-react"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the Dynamic import() by a require.ensure().

```
const MyPlugin = require.ensure([], function (require) {
    const plugin = require('./plugins/MyPlugin/MyPlugin.jsx');
    return new plugin.default;
}, "MyPlugin");
```