# Avoid duplicate code in bundle on dynamic import of webpack

Tags: webpack, shared-libraries, webpack-3, lerna

I have two lerna packages. Both have lodash as peer dependency. And, on the main webpack, I am importing the package dynamically on click of separate buttons. 
Separate chunk file is created for each package. However, each chunk file contains lodash code as duplicated. How can I avoid this? Is there any way to check if all dependencies are loaded, then exclude to load again?

You can see the code in [Github](https://github.com/jintoppy/lerna-inner-dependency). This is a simplified version of what I am expecting.

I am looking for solution in Webpack3.

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is similar to [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812595/how-to-prevent-dynamic-import-to-duplicate-a-bundle). However, solution provided is not working for me. I tried with import as well as require.ensure. Both gave the same output bundle.